# Positioning a content div below img only div

Tags: css, html, height, positioning

In a page I work on I have a div that contains an animation with changing images (with CSS) and below it is a wrapper div for the content, like that:

```
<div id="animation">
     <img ...>
     ...
     <img ...>
</div>
<div id="content">
     Some content
</div>
```

I've tried different methods: floats, clear, position, but I cannot make the content div to stay where it should, below the animation div - it overlaps it. The only solutions I found to partially work are to give the first div the height of the images (they all have equal width and height), but when I do that it breaks on different resolutions, or to give the images height of 100% and apply the above, but then the images look incredibly ugly on different resolutions.

How can I achieve my goal, preferably using CSS only?

Edit: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9FRxx/1/)

Edit 2: I used [this](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/) tutorial for the changing images.

Comment: can you show us the live demo your problem......

Comment: And please give your CSS code (+JSFiddle)

Comment: Done, the code is the same as in the JSFiddle apart from the image links. I have to use position:absolute for the animation and that must be the cause of why it is breaking, but if I don't use it the animation wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you have all the content in the top div as `position:absolute`. That way, the top div doesn't know how high it needs to be (i.e. it will be 0px high).
So the solution is to have one img not positioned; then the div is as high as this img and the content div will move down below it.

```
#cf4a img {
    position: absolute;
    left:0; top:0;
    width: 100%;
}

#cf4a img:first-child { /* one non-positioned child */
    position: static;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9FRxx/3/)

Comment: Thanks for this answer.

This fixes the divs overlapping problem, but only on 'normal' resolution. If I go higher, for example 1920x1080 they still overlap because of the changed heights. Is there any solution to that?

Comment: The jsfiddle site doesn't seem to load right now, so I can't check, but what exactly is the problem? As far as I can tell, the image width is simply 100% and it will keep its height to width ratio, no matter the screen resolution. Or does the content div have any special properties, like position of float or something?

Comment: Ah, the jsfiddle site works again. Now if I F11 my browser, the content div is still at the very bottom, when I scroll all the way down, past the enormous images. Do you see something else?

Comment: I fixed it putting an invisible image of the needed height below the animation that acts as a space holder. Inelegant solution, but works. Thank you for your help!